# How to Hide Internal Stack Trace Error in Node.js By Default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

I only want to display the TypeError line below, but **hide all the internal details** (the following 7 lines all starting with at).

```
 ~/Desktop/Practice> node "c:\Users\User\Practice\PracJS.js"
c:\Users\User\Practice\PracJS.js:6
let b = duck.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Bird)
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrototypeOf' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\User\Practice\PracJS.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)        
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)     
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I know I can do this with `Error.stackTraceLimit = 0` by including it in the file. But I want to do this by default.

Is there any way to point Node a config file (setting `Error.stackTraceLimit = 0` inside) so that whenever I run `node PracJS.js` (inside VSCode) so that it automatically applies `Error.stackTraceLimit = 0`?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `--stack-trace-limit` flag while running the javascript file. so in your case

```
node --stack-trace-limit=0 "c:\Users\User\Practice\PracJS.js"
```

OR

`export NODE_OPTIONS='--stack-trace-limit=0'`

It will be also worth mentioning to use `NODE_ENV` for these kind of cases. Some of the good packages (Express etc) uses this variable to control these things. so basically set `NODE_ENV=production` and you could also use this to control stack trace in your code.

Comment: Thank you! Inspired by your answer, I figured how to do it in VSCode (with the extension Code Runner)
I added this to setting.json
`"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node --stack-trace-limit=0",
  },`
And it works! Thank you!